# AttributeError: Error in getting tool information when using TableToTable tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, attributeerror

I am trying to use the arcpy.TableToTable_conversion tool in my python script, but seem to be getting the following error on the line

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("FINAL_NLPG", myTempWorkspace,outputTable)
```

The full traceback is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1463, in TableToTable
>       raise e
>   AttributeError: Error in getting tool information

The variable "FINAL_NLPG" is a table view of a join which contains approximately 999 records (the full table is 4.5 million records).

Any ideas on what might be causing the exception?

EDIT*****

```
for file in list_files:
    if file.startswith("Type_15"):
        arcpy.CopyRows_management(myDataSource + os.sep + file, r"in_memory\t15") #Row created to get a OID in table
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(r"in_memory\t15","T15_view")
    if file.startswith("Type_21"):
            arcpy.CopyRows_management(myDataSource + os.sep + file, r"in_memory\t21")#Row created to get a OID in table
            arcpy.MakeTableView_management(r"in_memory\t21","T21_view")
    if file.startswith("Type_24"):
        arcpy.CopyRows_management(myDataSource + os.sep + file, r"in_memory\t24")#Row created to get a OID in table
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(r"in_memory\t24","T24_view")

    #Join Table 15 with  Table 24 based on USRN
arcpy.AddJoin_management("T24_view", "USRN", "T15_view", "USRN", "KEEP_COMMON")

#Join Table 21 with  Table 24 based on UPRN
arcpy.AddJoin_management("T24_view", "t24.UPRN", "T21_view", "UPRN", "KEEP_COMMON")

arcpy.MakeTableView_management("T24_view","FINAL_NLPG","OBJECTID < 1000","") ## <1000 to see if the code works
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("FINAL_NLPG", myTempWorkspace,outputTable) # FAILS HERE
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("FINAL_NLPG", "in_memory",outputTable) #saving to in_memory --- SAME PROBLEM
```

My source files are CSV's which is the reason i am having to copyrows in_memory to get OID field, as from what i read i cannot do a join on a table that does not have an OID field.

Comment: What happens when you use the same line from the Table To Table tool dialog within ArcMap (assuming the "FINAL_NLPG" Table View is in the TOC to drag and drop in)?  If it gives the same error we can take Python/ArcPy out of the loop and just look at the tool.

Comment: The "FINAL_NLPG" is not in the TOC, the script is wholly in python, unless there is a way i can add a tableview created from the script into the TOC?

Comment: I cannot test at the moment but I think you could use AddTableView at 10.1 on but you are using 10.0. Instead can you perhaps get your script down to a snippet of 10 or less lines that still show the error and can be posted here to give more details of your process.

Comment: edited original question....slightly more than 10 lines :)

Comment: Does it work if you use a file geodatabase on disk rather than an in_memory workspace?  This could be another place where the functionality each supports diverges.